# Number of ways of grouping n labeled objects in r non-empty unlabeled groups.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $r \leq n$.

I know that the number of ways of grouping $n$ labeled objects in $r$ non-empty unlabeled groups is given by $S(n,r)$. (Stirling's number of 2nd kind)

But, also the number of ways of grouping $n$ labeled objects in $r$ non-empty labeled groups is given by $n! \cdot C(n-1,r-1)$ (stars and bars problem). Then why isn't the number of ways of grouping $n$ labeled objects in $r$ non-empty unlabeled groups equal to $\frac{1}{r!}[n! \cdot C(n-1,r-1)]$, by the latter formula?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Here is a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: The number of ways of distributing $n$ unlabeled objects into $r$ labeled nonempty groups is indeed $\binom{n-1}{r-1}$ but the number of ways of grouping $n$ labeled objects in $r$ non-empty labeled groups is not $n!\cdot \binom{n-1}{r-1}$.  Some scenarios will have been counted too many times.  For example, it should be easy to see that there is one and only one way to put $n$ objects into a single group, but your proposed formula would say that there are $n!$ ways.

Comment: @JMoravitz Could you point out where the stars and bars approach fails when counting labelled objects. For example, take the case of $n$ unlabeled objects into $r$ labeled groups (empty allowed). The number of ways is $C(n+r-1,r-1)$, because we shuffle $n$ stars and $r-1$ bars, and then divide by $n!$ and $(r-1)!$ because the stars and bars are identical. If the stars are not identical (that is for the problem of $n$ labeled objects into $r$ labeled groups), then again we shuffle $n$ stars and $r-1$ bars, but only divide by $(r-1)!$ as only the bars are identical. Where is the flaw?

Comment: The flaw is that within a single group, order should not matter.  You are doing it as though order matters *within* a group as well which is not the intention.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks.